# replicating 5000 users from primary active directory from primary to secondary active directory server

Tags: active-directory

I want to replicate more than 5000 users transactions from primary server to secondary active directory server. As I know windows 2000 server supporting 5000 operations per LDAP transaction. Please suggest best way to replicating more than 5000 users from primary to secondary active directory server.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that, if you have a functioning domain, *you* don't replicate anything. The domain controllers do it for you. If you have separate sites and subnets set up for the DCs, they might be on a schedule or throttled, but in general, it happens fairly quickly and without your input.

Now, my follow-up question is, what the hell are you actually doing? AD will use as many LDAP transactions as it needs to replicate anything that you're doing, I'm sure it won't be limited to one transaction and that's it. When companies with more than 5000 users add new domain controllers, that initial first sync doesn't typically cause problems, unless the new DC is across a slow WAN link (in which case, they should have staged it locally first and then shipped it.)

And are you still actually using Windows 2000?

/edit - also, please stop referring to primary and secondary/backup domain controllers? You made it clear that you're not running an NT 4.0 domain.

Answer (score 0):

Windows makes it so easy. Simply add another domain controller. dfs does it all in the background. It is part of how AD works. You can control replication with Sites and services. Properly define your sites and the cost of each site trunk.

Comment: Well, precisely speaking, not DFS. That's for files, including SYSVOL, which the DCs depend on, but does not include the AD database, which is where the accounts live.

Comment: What does it use? All I found was some information about RPC. Anyhow my comment about Sites and Services still stands.

Comment: Yes, of course Sites and Subnets (not services) is important, as I also mentioned in my answer - but the mechanism for keeping the NTDS database in sync across DCs is not DFS. It does use RPC, or sometimes SMTP if your links are really bad. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755994%28WS.10%29.aspx#w2k3tr_repto_how_imft

Comment: ಠ_ಠ Thanks. yes. ok. TIL... Btw afaik it is 'Active Directory Sites and Services' where this information is set (the name of the mmc snap in).

Comment: You're correct, that's the name of the MMC snapin. Which I'd forgotten, because it's asinine - there's no Services in there, you manage sites, subnets, and site-links.